# How to know when all superviews did load in nested views

Tags: ios, objective-c

As i understood, nested views are loaded from inner ones so `viewDidLoad` method for inner views run **before** superviews! and all parent and super properties are nil...

I need to initialize inner view when it loaded. Currently i've created methods in inner classes and call them in grand parent `viewDidLoad` method. Is there any similar method to be executed when screen is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

1. `viewDidLoad` is method of `UIViewController`. Not `UIView`. So you
   cant use `viewDidLoad` for `UIView`.
2. You mentioned ...

> I need to initialize inner view when it loaded.

In fact, it is good you add this view when it is properly initialized.

1. You can make use of `viewWillAppear` and put your checks and use `viewDidLoad` appropriately there after.

//Much better here:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath row] == lastRow){
        //end of loading
    }
}
```

Where `lastRow` is
[tableView numberOfRowsInSection: 0] - 1

Comment: Actually i have a `UITableViewController` in a container view in a `UIViewController`. Child is `UITableViewController`.